# Wifi on Esprimo V5535

Tags: wireless

i still have problems getting my Esprimo V5535 from Fujistsu Siemens, to open wlan.
I have looked everywhere and failed. It is an ath5k driver and the computer sees it. It says :

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:33:04:ab:23 
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:33ff:fe04:ab23/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:14272805 (14.2 MB)  TX bytes:1806907 (1.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:834 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:834 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:84643 (84.6 KB)  TX bytes:84643 (84.6 KB)
```

and when i write lspci, it says:

```
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AGP Port (virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge)
00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:03.0 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.1 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.3 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 02)
00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode (rev 03)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
00:1f.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 04)
```

Somehow the driver is not seen, or opened, by Ubuntu.
On another computer, a HP DV6000 with a B43 driver, i succeeded opening the driver, by reinstalling Ubuntu 10.04 and then updating this version.

How come, the old version will find and open then wlan, but the new Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 will not?

Iwconfig says:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions
```

Hope you can help me. I have spent several days, trying to find a solution. My patience has given me grey hairs.
Please understand that i am new to Linux and Ubuntu and do not understand the general commands in the OS. Have only been experimenting. And so far i did not succeed with wlan.
Otherwise i have spent days tryine Ubuntu 12.04, 13.10 and now reeinstalled 10.04 on two of my old harddiscs. (They seem to run better)

Best regards

Jan Aamand Petersen

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Answer (score 0):

This was what came, when i tryed to run, what Wild Man purposed:

Module                  Size  Used by
dm_crypt               22555  1 
rfcomm                 59026  0 
bnep                   19210  2 
bluetooth             341971  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32114  0 
ppdev                  17423  0 
arc4                   12509  2 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    50931  1 
ath5k                 141236  0 
snd_hda_intel          43326  3 
snd_hda_codec         169608  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
ath                    19435  1 ath5k
joydev                 17329  0 
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                94597  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
mac80211              534922  1 ath5k
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25157  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                55716  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28930  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
cfg80211              416271  3 ath5k,ath,mac80211
snd                    61270  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse                92648  0 
soundcore              12600  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18398  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
serio_raw              13189  0 
shpchp                 32265  0 
mac_hid                13077  0 
lp                     13359  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
vesafb                 13540  1 
pata_acpi              12886  0 
sata_sis               12711  2 
sis190                 22570  0 
mii                    13693  1 sis190
video                  19046  0 
sis_agp                13165  1 
Apr 15 15:05:48 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> bound
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:    address 100.82.185.157
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:    prefix 20 (255.255.240.0)
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:    gateway 100.82.176.1
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:    nameserver '89.249.14.50'
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:    nameserver '89.249.14.54'
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:    domain name 'emnet.dk'
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:05:49 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 15 15:05:50 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  DNS: starting dnsmasq...
Apr 15 15:05:50 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  [1397567150.723027] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:393] update(): dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
Apr 15 15:05:50 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  [1397567150.723083] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:395] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq': no such name
Apr 15 15:05:50 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Apr 15 15:05:50 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  (eth1): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 15 15:05:50 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  (eth1): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
Apr 15 15:05:51 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 15 15:05:51 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Activation (eth1) successful, device activated.
Apr 15 15:05:51 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 15 15:05:51 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  dnsmasq appeared on DBus: :1.21
Apr 15 15:05:51 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  (eth1): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 15 15:06:08 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  (eth1): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 15 15:06:08 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:06:08 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 15 15:06:08 aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 NetworkManager[866]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.

And also:

#### wireless info START

release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

kernel

Linux aamand-HP-Pavilion-dv6000 3.11.0-19-generic #33~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 12 21:17:09 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

lspci

00:04.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter [1039:0191] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions Device [1734:1125]
    Kernel driver in use: sis190

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x 802.11abg Wireless PCI Express Adapter (rev 01) [168c:3067]
    Kernel modules: ath5k

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

PCMCIA Card Info

rfkill

iw reg get

interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iwconfig

route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1

resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.1
search emnet.dk

nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth1  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            sis190
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:

  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes
  Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         192.168.1.101
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         192.168.1.1

  DNS:             89.249.14.50
  DNS:             89.249.14.54

NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

iwlist

iwlist channel

lsmod

modinfo

modules

lp

blacklist

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath5k.conf]
blacklist ath5k

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

udev rules

## PCI device 0x10de:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0 (forcedeth)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

## PCI device 0x1039:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0 (sis190)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

## PCI device 0x168c:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/0000:02:00.0 (ath5k)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

dmesg

[   28.752731] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   28.753226] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   38.816059] sis190 0000:00:04.0 eth1: mii ext = 0000
[   38.840024] sis190 0000:00:04.0 eth1: mii lpa=45e1 adv=01e1 exp=0007
[   38.840032] sis190 0000:00:04.0 eth1: link on 100 Mbps Full Duplex mode
[   38.840052] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready

#### wireless info END

But it did not help on my wireless connection. Still no driver that finds the router.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.